# Finding dynamic probabilities in R

Tags: r, probability, distributions

I have a sequence of independent uniform random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,... \sim \text{IID U}(1,3)$ and I need to compute the value:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k < a \Bigg).$$

The biggest issue that I faced here is that I don't know how to write a script in `R` to find the inner sum.  What I have is:

```
k = 10000
x <- vector(length = k)
for(i in 1:k){
    measurements <- runif(10000, min = 1, max = 3) # take 10,000 measurements
    above.threshold <- sum(measurements < 4) #count the number of values < 4
    rez <- above.threshold/length(measurements) # calculate the proportion of values < 4
    x[i] <- rez
}
sum(x)/k
```

The code is obviously not right because I don't know how to code the inner sum so that the sum of uniformly distributed random variables would be less than some fixed number.

I have googled a lot but haven't found a lot. Any help would be great!

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand the question correctly. Are you looking for `above.threshold <- sum(cumsum(measurements) < 4)`?

Comment: I guess not. I am looking for the way to find an approximate value for the formula that I included in my question. The code I attached is my 'failure' which obviously doesn't work well. @Base_R_Best_R

X_i are uniformly distributed random variables in the interval [1,3].

Comment: So for `a > 1` you will have `P(sum(X) < a) > 0`, even if the probability converges towards zero as n -> infinity.  Is the rate of convergence sufficient that the infinite sum of strictly positive values will yield a finite result?  As Limey pointed out, that's a math question rather than a computing question.

Comment: Since X~U(1,3), X>=1 is 1 hence P( Sum{1<=k<=n|Xk} < a) is 0 for n>a, and the outer sum is finite

Answer (score 1):

As a preliminary observation, it is worth noting that the quantity of interest here can be simplified to a finite sum.  Since $X_k \geqslant 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \geqslant n$ which implies that:

$$\mathbb{P} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k < a \Bigg) = 0
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } n \geqslant a.$$

Thus, for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ you can simplify the quantity of interest to the finite sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k < a \Bigg)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor a \rfloor} \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k < a \Bigg).$$

(You can also simplify some of the case on the other end using the upper bound of the random variables.)  Now, the sum of independent uniform random variables has a generalised [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).  With the bounds for your uniform distribution you have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{X_k-1}{2} \sim \text{IH}(n).$$

Exact computation of the inner probabilities is possible if $n$ is not too large, however it is tricky for large $n$ due to underflow issues involved in computing the CDF of the Irwin-Hall distribution.  You can use the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) to approximate the Irwin-Hall distribution by the normal distribution when $n$ is large, and this gives a simple and effective approximation.

---

In your question you are computing an empirical estimate from simulation, which is one approach you can take.  I will show you one way you can do this.
Taking a large number of simulations $S$ we can approximate the quantity of interest as:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k < a \Bigg) \approx
\frac{1}{S} \sum_{s=1}^S \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor a \rfloor} \mathbb{I} \Bigg( \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^{(s)} < a \Bigg).$$

This can be done using the following code in `R`.  In this code I generate a matrix of uniform random variables to cover all the simulations and then compute the indicators from these values.

```
compute.quantity <- function(a, sims = 1e6) {
  
  #Deal with trivial case
  A <- floor(a)
  if (A < 1) { return(0) }
  
  #Generate simulations
  X <- matrix(runif(sims*A, 1, 3), nrow = sims, ncol = A)
  
  #Compute approximation
  IND <- (apply(X, MARGIN = 1, FUN = 'cumsum') < a)
  sum(IND)/sims }
```

Here are some simulated values from the function.

```
#Simluate some approximate values of the quantity
set.seed(1)
compute.quantity(10)
[1] 4.542582

compute.quantity(20)
[1] 9.539944

compute.quantity(50)
[1] 24.54417

compute.quantity(100)
[1] 49.53875
```

Comment: (1) Did you notice you can also simplify the prefix of the sum?  Until $3n\ge a,$ $\Pr(\sum^nX_k \lt a)=1.$ (2) The CLT will likely give an excellent approximation once $a\gg 5$ or so and can provide a more accurate result than a simulation. In fact, for integral $a$ the Normal approximation is excellent as soon as $a\ge 2$!  For general $a$ it works very well once $a\ge 4.$ Here is an `R` implementation of the Normal approximation, if you wish to compare.  `f <- Vectorize(function(a) {
  n <- seq(n.0 <- ceiling(a/3), floor(a));
  n.0 - 1 + sum(pnorm(a, 2*n, sqrt(n/3)))
})`

Comment: BTW, here's simulation code that will run about an order of magnitude faster: `g <- Vectorize(function(a, N=1e6) {
  sum(apply(matrix(runif(N*floor(a), 1, 3), ncol=N), 2, cumsum) < a) / N
}, "a")`.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the feedback.  I have made a few edits to incorporate some of this.  I generally eschew ```apply``` in these answers since I find ```for``` loops to be a bit more expository (more akin to pseudo-code), but I've updated here in any case since it is quite elegant.

Comment: Understood.  Sometimes, though, the advantages of not having to wait for code to finish may outweigh the expressive advantages of the slower method, so it can be good to have both solutions.